# No numeric types to aggregate - change in groupby() behaviour?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with some groupy code which I'm quite sure once ran (on an older pandas version). On 0.9, I get *No numeric types to aggregate* errors. Any ideas?

```
In [31]: data
Out[31]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 2557 entries, 2004-01-01 00:00:00 to 2010-12-31 00:00:00
Freq: <1 DateOffset>
Columns: 360 entries, -89.75 to 89.75
dtypes: object(360)

In [32]: latedges = linspace(-90., 90., 73)

In [33]: lats_new = linspace(-87.5, 87.5, 72)

In [34]: def _get_gridbox_label(x, bins, labels):
   ....:             return labels[searchsorted(bins, x) - 1]
   ....: 

In [35]: lat_bucket = lambda x: _get_gridbox_label(x, latedges, lats_new)

In [36]: data.T.groupby(lat_bucket).mean()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-ed9c538ac526> in <module>()
----> 1 data.T.groupby(lat_bucket).mean()

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in mean(self)
    295         """
    296         try:
--> 297             return self._cython_agg_general('mean')
    298         except DataError:
    299             raise

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how, numeric_only)
   1415 
   1416     def _cython_agg_general(self, how, numeric_only=True):
-> 1417         new_blocks = self._cython_agg_blocks(how, numeric_only=numeric_only)
   1418         return self._wrap_agged_blocks(new_blocks)
   1419 

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in _cython_agg_blocks(self, how, numeric_only)
   1455 
   1456         if len(new_blocks) == 0:
-> 1457             raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
   1458 
   1459         return new_blocks

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Comment: for those end up here, the `.apply(pd.to_numeric)` DataFrame method might help.

Comment: I did end up here, @Foad, thanks. I could calculate .sum() and .count(), but not .mean(), on code that had been working yesterday. Sticking ```.apply(pd.to_numeric)``` in fixed it.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

How are you generating your data?

See how the output shows that your data is of 'object' type? the groupby operations specifically check whether each column is a numeric dtype first.

```
In [31]: data
Out[31]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 2557 entries, 2004-01-01 00:00:00 to 2010-12-31 00:00:00
Freq: <1 DateOffset>
Columns: 360 entries, -89.75 to 89.75
dtypes: object(360)
```

**look ↑**

Did you initialize an empty DataFrame first and then filled it? If so that's probably why it changed with the new version as before 0.9 empty DataFrames were initialized to float type but now they are of object type. If so you can change the initialization to `DataFrame(dtype=float)`.

You can also call `frame.astype(float)`

Comment: weird, so how do you groupby a field that contains a string? this seems more for scalar grouping than pivoting on values in a column.

Comment: @dcsan The error message is a bit misleading. You _can_ aggregate non-numeric types, using first() and similar methods at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation The error message triggers specifically when trying to do a numeric aggregation, e.g. mean()

Answer (score 16):

I got this error generating a data frame consisting of timestamps and data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':value}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(timestamp))
```

Adding the suggested solution works for me:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':value}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(timestamp), dtype=float))
```

Thanks Chang She!

Example:

```
                     data
2005-01-01 00:10:00  7.53
2005-01-01 00:20:00  7.54
2005-01-01 00:30:00  7.62
2005-01-01 00:40:00  7.68
2005-01-01 00:50:00  7.81
2005-01-01 01:00:00  7.95
2005-01-01 01:10:00  7.96
2005-01-01 01:20:00  7.95
2005-01-01 01:30:00  7.98
2005-01-01 01:40:00  8.06
2005-01-01 01:50:00  8.04
2005-01-01 02:00:00  8.06
2005-01-01 02:10:00  8.12
2005-01-01 02:20:00  8.12
2005-01-01 02:30:00  8.25
2005-01-01 02:40:00  8.27
2005-01-01 02:50:00  8.17
2005-01-01 03:00:00  8.21
2005-01-01 03:10:00  8.29
2005-01-01 03:20:00  8.31
2005-01-01 03:30:00  8.25
2005-01-01 03:40:00  8.19
2005-01-01 03:50:00  8.17
2005-01-01 04:00:00  8.18
                     data
2005-01-01 00:00:00  7.636000
2005-01-01 01:00:00  7.990000
2005-01-01 02:00:00  8.165000
2005-01-01 03:00:00  8.236667
2005-01-01 04:00:00  8.180000
```

Answer (score 8):

I got this done by :

```
data_frame.groupby(COL1).COL2.apply(np.mean).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3):

Got the same problem here, searched for so long just to realize my values were not floats but strings.

Here is what solved my issue:

```
df["column_name"] = pd.to_numeric(df["column_name"], downcast="float")
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when calling the `mean()` method from `groupby` on a column which was an `int/object` data type. It was solved by casting the column as a `float` like this:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype('float')
```