# Pandas max() and min() work but mean() gives "No numeric types" errror

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having some difficulties with the following Pandas code:

```
groupby_obj = features.groupby('Feature')
print groupby_obj["Value"].max() # This works
print groupby_obj["Value"].min() # This works
print groupby_obj["Value"].mean() #This doesn't work
```

The third line gives the following error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

This looks like the same error as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844529/no-numeric-types-to-aggregate-change-in-groupby-behaviour) but the answer isn't very easy to follow. Using `frame.astype(float)` won't work for me because some of the columns are strings. I could do `features[['Value']] = features[['Value']].astype(float)` but it seems messy (and probably involves an unnecessary copy operation).

Is there a way to specify certain types for certain columns when the DataFrame is instantiated? Or is completely different way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: why not just cast the `Value` column to `float`?

Comment: is there a way I can do that at DataFrame instantiation? or am I forced to do `features[['Value']] = features[['Value']].astype(float)` ?

Comment: sorry, idk about that one. but i believe there is a way.

Comment: OK - I think that's a separate SO question, thanks for your help!

Comment: you got it. good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as for the `min/max` issue, think about `strings`. you can have a `min/max` string (in the lowercase alphabet, `'a'` and `'z'` respectively), but a `mean` string makes no sense.

also, try casting the particular column (`Value`) to `float` and then do the math.