# pandas: resample No numeric types to aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, csv, resampling

I am trying to smoothen some data using pandas but I get stuck at an error telling me there are no numeric types to aggregate. I found various solutions on the internet, but I couldn't get past that error.

I am using data available at:

http://archive.luftdaten.info/2017-12-01/2017-12-01_sds011_sensor_3687.csv

I import the csv with:

```
sensor = pd.read_csv("all.csv", sep=";")
```

I parse the timestamp column with

```
sensor["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(sensor["timestamp"], infer_datetime_format=True, errors="coerce")
```

and set the timestamp as index

```
sensor = sensor.set_index("timestamp")
```

To keep it simple I extract a single column

```
p_1 = sensor["P1"]
```

I would now like to resample the data for one hour using:

```
p_1.resample("1H").mean()
```

But this returns an error:

```
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

From what I gathered searching for the error, I have to somehow convert the columns into numeric values but I couldn't find any function that would leave me with a table which would work.

Edit: I found this, but I really don't know how to apply this to my situation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30660772/9153439

Edit2 (solved):

I was able to resample the data by changing the datatype in `sensor` with

```
sensor["P1"] = sensor["P1"].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

I am quite sure that I tried this before on the `p_1` subset but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Nope, works for me.

Comment: Show us what `sensor.P1.dtype` gives you. If it's not `int` or `float` you can just write `sensor.P1 = sensor.P1.astype('float')` (or `int` if needed) and then try again. For the future, it's good to show a few rows of your data and the pandas version you're using

Comment: I am using pandas (0.21.1). `sensor.P1.dtype` gives me `dtype('O')`. However trying `sensor.P1 = sensor.P1.astype('float')` returns `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'P1'`

Comment: @Michael sounds like your dataframe has column headings as data