# Pandas/Python groupby and then calculate mean for another column within each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a table as the following. I want to group all the rows by the values in `ToD` and then calculate the `mean` for `LOS` for all the rows in the same group.

This is how I created the DataFrame

```
df_sim = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID','Type','Type_n','FT','ta','DoW','ToD','t_departure'])
```

I tried the following.

```
df_sim.groupby('ToD').LOS.mean()
```

The error I get is **DataError: No numeric types to aggregate**.

What is confusing to me is the following works. Im my mind, I now take the **sum** instead of **mean**.

```
df_sim[['ToD','LOS']].groupby('ToD').sum()
```

```
  ID     Type Type_n FT        ta  DoW ToD t_departure       LOS
0  0     ESI4      4  0  0.648446  Sun   0     3.87411   3.22567
1  1     ESI2      1  0  0.663228  Sun   0     1.42772  0.764489
2  2   A-ESI3      2  0   4.72354  Sun   4     4.90432  0.180779
3  3  NA-ESI3      3  0   5.26787  Sun   5     5.39109  0.123218
4  4  NA-ESI3      3  0   5.79297  Sun   5     5.98826  0.195283
5  5   A-ESI3      2  0   7.30924  Sun   7     7.49349  0.184249
6  6   A-ESI3      2  0   7.71666  Sun   7     8.20255  0.485886
7  7  NA-ESI3      3  0   8.22392  Sun   8     9.76091   1.53699
8  8     ESI4      4  0   8.30123  Sun   8     8.41346  0.112227
9  9     ESI4      4  0   8.40325  Sun   8     9.91045    1.5072
```

Comment: you should have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844529/no-numeric-types-to-aggregate-change-in-groupby-behaviour)

Comment: @pierresegonne Oh! I see what's your point. Let me try something.

Comment: @pierresegonne Thank you! I think I have figured something out. It works. But I am not sure it is the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I with help from the comment, we have figure something out like this.

```
df_sim = pd.DataFrame({'ID': int(),
                        'Type': str(),
                        'Type_n':int(),
                        'FT':int(),
                        'ta':float(),
                        'DoW': str(),
                        'ToD': int(),
                        't_departure':float()
                        },index=[])
```

However, I am not sure what `index=[]` is required. But it seems to be working.