# No numeric types to aggregate using groupby() and mean()

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby, xgboost

I am trying to determine the churn rate. If I try executing with `.size()` it works. But if I write it with `.mean()` it doesn't. I don't understand why is it not working because I need to find out the mean.

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
from pylab import rcParams
%matplotlib inline
import plotly.offline as pyoff
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score, train_test_split
import xgboost as xgb

#initate plotly
pyoff.init_notebook_mode()

#read data from csv and redo the data work we done before
df_data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\aayus\OneDrive\Desktop\College Project\4. Churn Prediction\churn-data.csv', encoding='latin1')
df_data.head(10)
df_data.info()

df_data.loc[df_data.Churn=='No','Churn'] = 0
df_data.loc[df_data.Churn=='Yes','Churn'] = 1

df_plot = df_data.groupby('gender').Churn.size().reset_index()
```

this works. But if I change the last line with

```
df_plot = df_data.groupby('gender').Churn.mean().reset_index()
```

It gives "No numeric types to aggregate".

```
DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-1-4875501f5fb5> in <module>
     26 df_data.loc[df_data.Churn=='No','Churn'] = 0
     27 df_data.loc[df_data.Churn=='Yes','Churn'] = 1
---> 28 f_plot = df_data.groupby('gender').Churn.mean().reset_index()

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in mean(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1222         """
   1223         nv.validate_groupby_func("mean", args, kwargs, ["numeric_only"])
-> 1224         return self._cython_agg_general(
   1225             "mean", alt=lambda x, axis: Series(x).mean(**kwargs), **kwargs
   1226         )

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
    905 
    906         if len(output) == 0:
--> 907             raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")
    908 
    909         return self._wrap_aggregated_output(output)

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-1-4875501f5fb5> in <module>
     26 df_data.loc[df_data.Churn=='No','Churn'] = 0
     27 df_data.loc[df_data.Churn=='Yes','Churn'] = 1
---> 28 f_plot = df_data.groupby('gender').Churn.mean().reset_index()

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in mean(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1222         """
   1223         nv.validate_groupby_func("mean", args, kwargs, ["numeric_only"])
-> 1224         return self._cython_agg_general(
   1225             "mean", alt=lambda x, axis: Series(x).mean(**kwargs), **kwargs
   1226         )

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
    905 
    906         if len(output) == 0:
--> 907             raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")
    908 
    909         return self._wrap_aggregated_output(output)

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-1-4875501f5fb5> in <module>
     26 df_data.loc[df_data.Churn=='No','Churn'] = 0
     27 df_data.loc[df_data.Churn=='Yes','Churn'] = 1
---> 28 f_plot = df_data.groupby('gender').Churn.mean().reset_index()

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in mean(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1222         """
   1223         nv.validate_groupby_func("mean", args, kwargs, ["numeric_only"])
-> 1224         return self._cython_agg_general(
   1225             "mean", alt=lambda x, axis: Series(x).mean(**kwargs), **kwargs
   1226         )

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
    905 
    906         if len(output) == 0:
--> 907             raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")
    908 
    909         return self._wrap_aggregated_output(output)

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

I would really appreciate the help.
This is the output of df_data.head(10)
[image]

Telco data set

Comment: Can you append the copy-pastable output of this: df_data.head(10)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you don't have any other values in the Churn column. Use df_data['Churn'].value_counts().
It will be awesome if you can share first 10 rows of your data.

Comment: It has 21 columns  but I can say this, gender column only has Female and Male variables and Churn column has only Yes and No variables.

Comment: I believe that you are using the Telco data set. I tried running your code and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Yes, Sir, I am using the telco dataset. I tried using running it on a colleague's laptop and it is working there. I cannot understand why is it not working on my device.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844529/no-numeric-types-to-aggregate-change-in-groupby-behaviour This might be helpful for you.

Comment: Also make sure that you are using the latest version of Pandas.