# I am trying to create a table from a csv file to give me a proportion for a variable

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

The following code is what I have but it is throwing a code saying no numeric types to aggregate.
The code:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
link = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dvanderelst-python-class/python-class/spring2021/assignment_data/young_people_survey.csv'
data = pandas.read_csv(link,index_col=0)

data.groupby(['Age','Smoking']).agg(np.mean)
table = pandas.pivot_table(data, index= ['Age'], columns=None, values=['Smoking'],
aggfunc={'Smoking':[np.mean]},fill_value=0)
```

I am trying to get a table that looks like this:
[Example of what table should look like][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Li38.png

The error message I am getting when I run in pandas:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyTun.png)

Comment: Can you print data.head() and add it to the question? The error messege  is because none of the columns in this dataframe is of numeric type i.e. float/int

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844529/no-numeric-types-to-aggregate-change-in-groupby-behaviour for more detailed discussion in this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No numeric types to aggregate - change in groupby() behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844529/no-numeric-types-to-aggregate-change-in-groupby-behaviour)

Comment: The problem is in the last line of the code. You are trying to aggregate a non numeric column Smoking.

Answer (score 0):

In your groupby you're saying which columns you are grouping (Age and Smoking) but not which column to calculate the mean. When it tries to calculate the mean of the Smoking column with values 'never smoked', 'former smoker' is says that this is not a numeric column.

If you change your groupby to

```
data.groupby(['Age','Smoking']).agg({'Height': 'mean', 'Weight': 'mean'})
```

You will get the average height and weight for each combination of Age and Smoking category

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
link = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dvanderelst-python-class/python-class/spring2021/assignment_data/young_people_survey.csv'
data = pandas.read_csv(link,index_col=0)
data['Age'] = data['Age'].astype(float)
data.groupby(['Age','Smoking']).agg(np.mean)
table = pandas.pivot_table(data, index= ['Age'])
```

This would give a table as below

[image]